# Connect points on map in matlab with earth curvature

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I want a map with some points and I want to have a distance line connecting those points that also shows the curvature of the earth. Is that possible? Here is some example code:

```
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp','UseGeoCoords',true);
axesm ('vperspec', 'Frame', 'on', 'Grid', 'off');
point1_lat = 25;
point1_lon = 110;
point2_lat = 45;
point2_lon = 130;
geoshow(landareas,'DefaultFaceColor',[0.9 0.9 0.9],'DefaultEdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
geoshow(point_lat,point_lon,'DisplayType','point','LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.1172 0.5625 1.0000],'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',12)
geoshow(point2_lat,point2_lon,'DisplayType','point','LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.8594 0.0781 0.2344],'Marker','^', 'MarkerSize',12)
```

Comment: I doubt that your only question is: is it possible? cause the answer to this will be clearly: yes. You should start explain us your problem in more detail. And why you are failing to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `track2` function from the Mapping Toolbox to get a list of coordinates along the line, then plot with `geoshow`.

For example

```
point1_lat = 25;
point1_lon = 110;
point2_lat = 45;
point2_lon = 130;
[lat,lon] = track2(point1_lat, point1_lon, point2_lat, point2_lon);
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp','UseGeoCoords',true);
axesm ('vperspec', 'Frame', 'on', 'Grid', 'off', 'Origin', [point1_lat+45, point1_lon]);
geoshow(landareas,'DefaultFaceColor',[0.9 0.9 0.9],'DefaultEdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);
geoshow(point1_lat,point1_lon,'DisplayType','point','LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.1172 0.5625 1.0000],'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',12)
geoshow(point2_lat,point2_lon,'DisplayType','point','LineWidth',2, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.8594 0.0781 0.2344],'Marker','^', 'MarkerSize',12)
geoshow(lat,lon,'LineWidth',2,'Marker','none');
```

which results in

[image]